# Python: Different behaviour running from crontab than diorectly

Tags: python, cron, python-3.6, solaris

Solaris environment. This script runs fine when I run directly but crontab does not do anything in it

Code:

```
19 * * * *   python3 usr/src/utils/CE/ce_common_utils/ce_env_utils.py
```

I'm not getting the difference between crontabs environment and bash's. Anything obvious to check/correct?

Answer (score 0):

Crontab starts in the given user's home directory.  Is `usr/src/...` in that directory or do you need to give the full path to that script?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to provide PYTHONPATH value to the script